Unity Randomized Animation is synchronized across all prefab instances
As per title, I am randomizing animation using the following script:
private IEnumerator RandomizeAnimation()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      var rand = Random.Range(0, 100);
      switch (rand)
      {
        case > 90 and <= 95:
          animator.SetTrigger(TurnLeft);
          yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
          break;
        case > 95:
          animator.SetTrigger(TurnRight);
          yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
          break;
        default:
          yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
          break;
      }
    }
  }

The animation is synchronized across all prefab instances. When the trigger is set for one of the instances, it is also set for other instances. I tried googling the question, but it is very hard for me to phrase. For the example purposes, you can assume that each animation is shorter than 3 seconds.
I tried to check if all the prefab instances refer to their respective animator. I also tried to make the same script inside the animator, which resulted in the same behaviour. Furthermore, I tried searching for how to do a deep copy of an animator, which would require to duplicate the asset in-game. Additionally, I tried to create a new instance of the runtime animator controller, and swap it with the existing one, to no help (as for example here: My animator is creating Simultaneous animation?).
If anyone knows how to solve this problem, I will be thankful for any help.
